# Can you use a USB output splitter as an input viewer

Tags: nintendo-switch

I wanna have an input viewer for my switch. However, I need a board that is about 70 bucks and I don’t want to spend that much on it. Could I use a USB output splitter like this:

[https://www.amazon.com/Female-Dual-Extra-Power-Cable/dp/B00M4SH7KW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00M4SH7KW)

for this? I would think I could plug in my pro controller and one output into the switch and the other into my computer. If not, what is another cheap way to do this

Comment: Hello and welcome to Arqade. What do you mean by "Input viewer" ? Do you want to be able to get the Switch Image on your computer ?

Comment: Or do you want to see which button is pressed on your controller ?

Comment: I want to know if I can use that to sent the controller inputs simultaneously to both the switch and pc. So yeah, I wanna show which button I pressed for speedruns and stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the comments, no, you can't use this specific splitter.

It's said in the description that the second connector can only be used for transmitting power, not data.

I'm afraid you need to buy something a bit more expensive to do what you want to do (be it an onboard or external card).

Comment: Thank you! Anything you know that might help?